# onDocumentLoad not triggered

Tags: ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Is anyone else finding that the `ng2-pdfjs-viewer` Angular library doesn't ever trigger the `onDocumentLoad` function ?

```
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer 
    #externalPdfViewer
    [viewerId]="pdfName"
    (onDocumentLoad)="onDocumentLoaded($event)"
    zoom="page-width"
    [fullScreen]=true
    [pdfSrc]="attachment.pdfName"
    [downloadFileName]="pdfName"> 
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

Lots of people have noticed that if the pdf is open *in a different window*, then they get this behavior, but for me, my pdf is in the same window.

The "ng2-pdfjs-viewer.component.ts" file contains a `receiveMessage` function which is where an `onDocumentLoad` function would get called, but I added some logging around this function, and this entire function never gets called.

```
public receiveMessage(viewerEvent)  {
    ...
    else if (this.onDocumentLoad && event == "pagesLoaded") {
         this.onDocumentLoad.emit(param);
    }
```

My pdf is displayed perfectly by the library, but I need to know when the pdf has finished rendering, so I can search for, and highlight certain words in it.

Answer (score 1):

Below seems to work for me

```
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer
  #pdfViewer
  [openFile]="false"
  [download]="true"
  [print]="true"
  [viewBookmark]="false"
  viewerId="document"
  (onDocumentLoad)="loadComplete()"
  pagemode="none"
>
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

The major difference what is see is in your code you pass it as `[viewerId]` while i pass it without the square brackets